# nginx forward partial uri for versioned api

Tags: redirect, nginx, nginx-location

Is there a variable I can use to redirect a partial uri?  I have

```
location /api/v1/ {
    proxy_pass...;
}

location /api/ {
    return 302 /api/v1/$request_uri;
}
```

But, if I call a url like `/api/user`, it redirects to `/api/v1/api/user`.  How can I redirect to `/api/v1/user`?  Is there a variable that returns the url with the location stripped off?  I tried `$uri` and `$document_uri` with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
rewrite ^/api/((?!v1/).*)$ /api/v1/$1 redirect;

location /api/v1/ {
    proxy_pass...;
}
```